# Error while transforming character containing day (as %a or %A) in date

Tags: r, date, date-formatting

## My problem

I would like to transform this character:

```
"Mon-March, 2015"
```

To a date... Using references on dates ([here](https://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html) ) i found that my format is `%A-%B, %Y`

But performing it return NA

```
> as.Date("Monday-March, 2017", format = "%A-%B, %Y")
[1] NA
```

Samething with %a

```
> as.Date("Mon-March, 2017", format = "%a-%B, %Y")
[1] NA
```

But it works perfectly if day is in digits:

```
> as.Date("01-March, 2015", "%d-%B, %Y")
[1] "2015-03-01"
```

## My session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=C                     

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3 tools_3.4.3    yaml_2.1.16
```

Comment: No surprise it can't handle. Which specific day `Monday-March, 2017` is?

Comment: Woo didn't thought of this one :) Thanks

Comment: When you get over this problem I think you're also likely to have problems with the French locale. IIRC %A , %a use weekday names and abbreviations from the current locale (Lundi/lun, not Monday/Mon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"Monday-March, 2017"` is not a valid date; there are plenty of Mondays in a month (specifically the March of 2017 had 4 Mondays: 6th, 13th, 20th and 27th). If you also provide the day of month value, then the conversion should work (although passing in the weekday does not make sense in that case).

```
> as.Date("Monday-March, 2017", format = "%A-%B, %Y")
[1] NA
> as.Date("Monday-1, March, 2017", format = "%A-%d, %B, %Y")
[1] "2017-03-01"
```

It is not clear what you want to achieve, maybe if you show us the bigger picture?